# Handling timezones when extracting Calendar data to a Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, timezone, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sheets

I'm working on a little Google Apps Script that will export event data from a selected Google Calendar to a new Google Spreadsheet for a selected date range.  One problem I'm having is that the times when copied over to the spreadsheet are off by three hours.  Any suggestions as to how to handle this and display the event times correctly?

Here's my code so far: (It's a work-in-progress)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("change");
  var picker1 = app.createDatePicker().addValueChangeHandler(handler).setId("picker1");
  var picker2 = app.createDatePicker().addValueChangeHandler(handler).setId("picker2");
  var pickerpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  pickerpanel.add(picker1);
  pickerpanel.add(picker2);
  panel.add(pickerpanel);
  var lb = app.createListBox(false).setId('lbCalSelId').setName('lbCalSelect');

  lb.setVisibleItemCount(3);
  var cals = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  for (var i=0; i<cals.length;i++) {
    lb.addItem(cals[i].getName(),cals[i].getId());
  }
  panel.add(lb);

  var button = app.createPushButton().setText("Export").setId("button");
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('doExport').addCallbackElement(panel);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  panel.add(button);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;  
}

function change(eventInfo) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  if (eventInfo.parameter.picker1) {
    UserProperties.setProperties({"DateRangeStart":eventInfo.parameter.picker1});
    app.add(app.createLabel("Start date " + eventInfo.parameter.picker1));
  }
  else if (eventInfo.parameter.picker2) {
    UserProperties.setProperties({"DateRangeEnd":eventInfo.parameter.picker2});
    app.add(app.createLabel("End date" + eventInfo.parameter.picker2));
  }

  return app;
}

function doExport(eventInfo) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var calId = eventInfo.parameter.lbCalSelect;
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  var rangeStart = UserProperties.getProperty("DateRangeStart");
  var rangeEnd = UserProperties.getProperty("DateRangeEnd");
  app.add(app.createLabel("The button was clicked!"));
  if (rangeStart && rangeEnd) {
   app.add(app.createLabel("exporting..."));
   var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(rangeStart), new Date(rangeEnd));
   var eventsData = [];
   var headerRow = ['Title','Start Time','End Time','Location','Description'];
   for (var i=0; i < events.length; i++) {
     var eventData = [];
     eventData.push(events[i].getTitle());
     eventData.push(events[i].getStartTime());
     eventData.push(events[i].getEndTime());
     eventData.push(events[i].getLocation());
     eventData.push(events[i].getDescription());
     eventsData.push(eventData);
   }
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("Export of " + cal.getName() + " from " + rangeStart + " to " + rangeEnd);
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   var destRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, events.length, headerRow.length);
   destRange.setValues(eventsData);
  }
  else {
   app.add(app.createLabel("Range not specified."));
  }

  return app;
}
```

Comment: Make sure the timezone of the calendar is the same as the timezone that your spreadsheet is. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();`. Also, is it the range times that are off? or the calendar event times?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I just set the timezone of the spreadsheet to the same timezone as the calendar and it worked like a charm.

```
ss.setSpreadsheetTimeZone(cal.getTimeZone());
```